# How to mock PropertyConfigurator.configure() with PowerMockito?

Tags: java, log4j, mockito, powermockito

I am using log4j to log messages and the log4j properties are coming from user. I have used `PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties)` to configure the properties provided by the user.

While writing test cases i am using PowerMock to mock `PropertyConfigurator` and configure method as well. `configure()` method is a void static method. I am getting nullpointer exception while trying to do so. Any way to do that?

I have tried doing

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertyConfigurator.class);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(PropertyConfigurator.class);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(slf4jPropertiesMock);
```

This is not working.

If possible, is there any option of doing some other way around where i will be getting seme result without using `PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties)`? In that case unit testing will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this configuration in on your test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(PropertyConfigurator.class)
public class Test{
```

Your mocking should look like this:

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(PropertyConfigurator.class)
      .configure(Mockito.any(Properties.class);
```

**Without PowerMockito**

Wrap the `PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties)` calls into a package method:

```
public class C{
   ...
   void configure(Properties p){
     PropertyConfigurator.configure(p);
   }
```

Spy the C class and mock the configure method:

```
C c = new C();
C sSpy = Mockito.spy(c);
Mockito.doNothing().when(c).configure(Mockito.any(Properties.class);
```